# Windows service cannot read file with owner other than LOCAL_SERVICE

Tags: c++, windows, file, service

I have a Windows service written in C++ with the Win32 API. Before entering in "service" mode, the C++ program tries to read a configuration file specified as an absolute path. But the program cannot read it and exits. Some debugging leaves me to suspect that this is because of file ownership.

Question is, how can I modify the file ownership (preferably with a power-shell script) , so that the file can be read?

Here are the relevant parts

1. main program (exits, file cannot be read)

```
int main()
{
  std::string cfg_file_name = config::get_config(config::comm_config_file);
  if (cfg.read(cfg_file_name) < 0)
  {
    events::start_log(cfg.log_path, cfg.log_spdlog_level);
    SPDLOG_CRITICAL("Cannot read: " + cfg_file_name);
    return 1;
  }
```

2. function get_config() uses some Win32 API calls to get the executable path (where the file is located) and concatenates it with the file name, to get an absolute path

```
std::string config::get_config(const std::string& config_name)
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  std::string s = config::get_executable_path();

  //this is done before log starts; it will be written to C:\Windows\System32 as a first log/debugging tool
  std::ofstream ofs("comm.txt");
  ofs << "GetModuleFileName: " << s << std::endl;

  TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buf);
  ofs << "GetCurrentDirectory: " << buf << std::endl;

  //change the current directory of the process to be the executable path
  if (SetCurrentDirectory(s.c_str()) == 0)
  {
    ofs << "SetCurrentDirectory" << std::endl;
  }

  GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buf);
  ofs << "GetCurrentDirectory: " << buf << std::endl;

  s += config_name;
  ofs.close();
  return s;
#else
  return config_name;
#endif
}
```

3. service is created by a power-shell script

```
sc.exe create _comm_ftp_server binPath= "$install_dir\ftp_server.exe" start= auto obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" password= " "
```

4. to debug it, I wrote a simple test service that writes a file and reads that same file, with no problem (so, a file can be read)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string path = config::get_executable_path();
  cfg.log_path = path;
  events::start_log(cfg.log_path, "trace", true);

  //A service process has a SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY structure for each service that it can start. 
  //The structure specifies the service name and a pointer to the service main function for that service.
  //The main function of a service program calls the StartServiceCtrlDispatcher 
  //function to connect to the service control manager (SCM)

  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY service_table[] =
  {
      { (LPSTR)service_name, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)service_main },
      { NULL, NULL }
  };

  if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(service_table))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//service_main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void WINAPI service_main(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv)
{
  service_handle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(service_name, service_handler);
  if (service_handle == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  service_stop_event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
  if (service_stop_event == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  report_status(SERVICE_START_PENDING);

  report_status(SERVICE_RUNNING);
  SPDLOG_INFO("service running..." + std::to_string(current_state));

  HANDLE thread_service = 0;
  thread_service = CreateThread(NULL, 0, service_thread, NULL, 0, NULL);
  WaitForSingleObject(thread_service, INFINITE);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //service shutdown requested 
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  CloseHandle(thread_service);

  report_status(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
  SPDLOG_INFO("service stop pending..." + std::to_string(current_state));
  CloseHandle(service_stop_event);

  report_status(SERVICE_STOPPED);
  SPDLOG_INFO("service stopped..." + std::to_string(current_state));
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//service_thread
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DWORD WINAPI service_thread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
  std::string path = cfg.log_path;
  SPDLOG_INFO("service started in..." + cfg.log_path);
  path += "\\test.txt";

  size_t i = 0;
  while (WaitForSingleObject(service_stop_event, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    write_txt_file(path, "writing...#" + std::to_string(i));
    i++;
    Sleep(10000);
    read_txt_file(path);
  }
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//write_txt_file
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void write_txt_file(const std::string& file_name, const std::string& input)
{
  FILE* f = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "a+");
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", input.c_str());
  fclose(f);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//read_txt_file
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void read_txt_file(const std::string& file_name)
{
  std::ifstream ifs;
  ifs.open(file_name);
  if (!ifs.is_open())
  {
    SPDLOG_ERROR("Cannot open: " + file_name);
    return;
  }
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(ifs, line))
  {
    SPDLOG_INFO("Line: " + line);
  }
  ifs.close();
}
```

5. Examining the file written by the test service in Windows explorer (Properties->Details) reveals a file owner as LOCAL_SERVICE

The file that must be read has owner "Administrators"

This leaves me to suspect that this is the problem. How can the file ownership be changed, or is there a way to create the service with privileges  that can read any file ?

reference for SC.EXE Create

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create

To read the file, std::ifstream is used (default read only)

```
int config::config_t::read(const std::string& fname)
{
  try
  {
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);
    ifs >> configuration_json;
    ifs.close();
    from_json(configuration_json, *this);
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    SPDLOG_ERROR(e.what());
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+change+file+owner+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: who is owner of file not play any role (if you not request `WRITE_DAC` access). your error - what access you request when open file ? you need read only access. so `FILE_GENERIC_READ`

Comment: @RbMn, good suggestion, but I use std::ifstream to read the file, which I believe has a default of read-only? see the EDIT on the post

Answer (score 0):

The read error was because the library JSON for modern C++

https://github.com/nlohmann/json

detects an error reading the last entry of this file because of the comma ","

```
{
  "archive_path":"D:\\archive",
  "test_comm_input_path":"D:\\test_comm_input_path",
}
```

in the reading function

```
int config::config_t::read(const std::string& fname)
{
  //this is done before log starts; it will be written to the executable path as a first log/debugging tool in service mode
  std::ofstream ofs("comm.txt");
  try
  {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    std::ios_base::iostate mask = ifs.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit;
    ifs.exceptions(mask);
    ifs.open(fname);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
      ofs << "open fail: " << fname << std::endl;
      ofs.close();
      return -1;
    }
    else
    {
      ofs << "open: " << fname << std::endl;
    }
    ifs >> configuration_json;
    ifs.close();
    from_json(configuration_json, *this);
    ofs << "read: " << fname << std::endl;
    ofs.close();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    ofs << "json read: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    ofs.close();
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

where

```
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, config::config_t& c)
{
  if (j.contains("archive_path"))
  {
    j.at("archive_path").get_to(c.archive_path);
  }
}
```